# How to add a css class into my function

Tags: jquery, css

Just starting out with jquery. I have written the following function:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $('.tb-to-side-menu > li > a').on('click', function() {

        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $(this.hash).offset().top
        }, 1000);

        return false;
    });
});
```

This is for a 'one page' styled site, so when the use clicks on the nav they get smooth scrolling down. Problem is that I have a sticky nav and the content is sliding too far up. Is it possible to add a css class in with jquery that allows for the height of my nav div?

Thanks

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/addclass/

Comment: Thanks, works. Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I've understood the issue, you could subtract the height of the fixed header from `$(this.hash).offset().top`, for example:

```
$('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $(this.hash).offset().top - $('#fixedHeader').height()
}, 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:
$(ele).addClass("classname")